# Emacs freezes for a minute

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, freeze, emacs

This is a problem that started a few weeks or so ago. Emacs suddenly freezes, while all the other windows (and the mouse) continue to work. After a minute or so, it unfreezes.

This happens several times a day. I don't even know how to get started on debugging/documenting this. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a powerful workstation, and I use Emacs a lot on small text files and program code.

I suspect this is related to a graphics driver update (my graphics card is an NVIDIA), and not related to Emacs per se. I never had this problem on the very same computer until recently.

How can I fix this?

Comment: In the Old Days, "EMACS" meant "Eight Megabytes And Constantly Swapping" - it's bigger now. How much RAM, how much SWAP? What is a "powerful workstation"? Does `journalctl` show any interesting messages at the time of the freeze?

Comment: You might be better off asking this on [emacs]. In the meantime, do you get the same issue if you run `emacs -Q`? Can you try that and see if you can reproduce the error? If you can't, we'll know it's something to do with your emacs config.

Comment: Thanks. After a few weeks the problem has disappeared as miraculously as it appeared, so this is no longer an issue.